# Invited for "a day in the office" after interview, what should I expect?

Tags: recruitment, germany

I've recently engaged in a recruiting process with some company in Berlin as a web developer.
After several skype interviews with a clear expression of the company managers satisfaction of my skills and personality, I've been invited to Berlin to spend a day with them on their expense.

Since this is my first time in an international process, and also the first time I'm getting such a "come over" offer, I do not know what to expect and what is going to happen when I get there.
However I understand it is fairly common in Berlin as a step in the recruitment process.

What should I expect when I meet them?

Comment: I did this once. The whole office was chaos, practicals jokes everywhere. One dude took off his belt and wrapped it around his head cause he got tired while holding the phone. Spent 2 years there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Being satisfied with your professional skills, they'd like to evaluate your softer skills, like how you interact with others - in order to deem whether you socially are a good fit for the team and company.

They'd like to see whether you in working situations perhaps are too passive, too eager or just the right mix of a listener and a self-starter. And socially, where are you on the scale of being a party animal versus a wallflower?

You'll probably be introduced to co-workers, join a project meeting and go to lunch. Even though they are evaluating you, try not to treat it as a test and just be yourself. Don't try to hard, but 'follow their lead' and mirror their behavior; if they joke a lot, join in. If they don't, then don't.

For some, this may be easier said than done. I tend to do it by flipping the situation and in my mind treating it as if I am evaluating them as prospective employers and not the other way around.

Comment: This is a good answer. They are looking to see if your face fits in their team. Be prepared to talk technical with colleagues, but it is probably more  of a social exercise.

Comment: "I am evaluating them as prospective employers" - that's a big part of it. You get to see working conditions, gauge the atmosphere in the office and see what the area around the office is like. You deciding if you like them is just as important as them liking you. This is a great opportunity, enjoy it.