# Last interview and lunch with team tomorrow - what to expect?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, recruitment, startup

I've passed three interviews so far, two technical and one with HR.

They told me to come by tomorrow for a 1.5 hour interview with the CTO and then meet the team and have lunch with them.

Got any pointers on what to expect and is it usually more of a social/organisational meetup?

Comment: Not sure how similar it is to this question 
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/84812/invited-for-a-day-in-the-office-after-interview-what-should-i-expect

Comment: Don't order spaghetti.

Comment: Order something appropriate: Avoid overly smelly/messy foods, don't get alcoholic drinks. Don't try and be someone you're not, just relax, and use it as a chance to meet the team(s) and learn some more about them. They're not gonna ask you how to code something mid-bite.

Comment: @n_palum `don't get alcoholic drinks` and `Don't try and be someone you're not, just relax`. If everyone else is having alcoholic drinks and and you feel comfortable with having a beer then certainly take the beer. Read the situation of the people your with and relax. They are just seeing if your going to make a good fit to the team, so it's more of an interview of your interpersonal skills.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are just a step from getting the job, the CTO may want to get involved in the hiring process to ensure you fit in the organization's culture and explain at high level how they work, and the lunch part is almost like a welcome to the team, obviously it's an oportunity to see how you will get along with them. 
I wouldn't worry if I were you, clearly you did a good job so far.

Comment: Any questions I have to expect ? I guess the coding questions are behind me..
I guess by high level you mean generally how they work ?

Comment: why I mean with high level is stuff like the vision and culture of the company and the  IT department. I don't expect difficult questions from him, but you have the chance to ask important question to the boss, things like career, the future of the company, etc

Answer (score 3):

Not everything is a test. If you cleared 3 rounds of interviews AND got invitation for lunch with CTO, I think you will be fine, and this is just a social thing. Granted, if you do say something incredibly inappropriate (something racist, sexist or similar nature) you may still flunk it. But I would not worry too much if I were you.